# Sizing images with a blank source

Tags: html, css

I've got a long page, built with Angular.  The images on the page are lazy-loaded so that the `src` is not set until the image is scrolled into view.

The container is flexible and the images should never scale larger than their dimensions (which I know and can set on a `style` attribute)

Right now I've having issues getting the images without a set source to scale properly.

**TL;DR**
I want `<img src='pic.jpg'/>` and `<img src=''/>`to take up the exact same amount of space inside a flexible container with maximum sizes.

**DEMO: http://codepen.io/chrismbarr/pen/xGgGRq?editors=110**

---

**HTML** (this will be generated from JavaScript where we know the dimentions ahead of time)

```
<div class="container" style='max-width: 500px; max-height: 700px;'>
  Image with a source
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/700/cats/2/" />
</div>

<div class="container" style='max-width: 500px; max-height: 700px;'>
  Image with no source
  <img src="" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
  display:block;
  max-width: 100%;
}  

img[src=''],
img:not([src]){
  //no image source
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a demo of the image sizes being hard-set so they are no longer flexible.  This is what I want to avoid: http://codepen.io/chrismbarr/pen/JdEYMe

Comment: Well. If you know that the width 500px and height 700px is always the same you could just set height:700px. But what I understand you want is basically you want to know the size of an img src before you even load/resize it. I just cannot imagine how you would do that with pure html/css

Comment: onload page call script function to get images sources and get information and compare. according to the value you just give largest values of image to both <img> tag

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use lazy loading? Bandwidth issues? If so, any solutions you're going to get will be negating the advantages of the lazy loading technique. How about simply loading them non-lazily.

Comment: @Tom-OliverHeidel no, I already have all the image dimensions, I just don't want to load them all for bandwidth/performance reasons (many of them may be large animated gifs).  I could just hard-set the sizes on the images, but then they aren't flexible.

Comment: to further explain what I want: I have the image dimensions, but an image without a `src` set doesn't maintain the correct aspect ratio.

Comment: How about simply reviving ye olde 1×1px `blank.gif` here …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that you know the dimensions of every image ahead of time, I almost always recommend the combination of a plain ol' `<div>` and the `background-image` property. You don't have to pander to the idiosyncrasies of the `<img>` tag, and you [still get support for animated .gifs](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/d83Kw/1/).

[I whipped up this quick Codepen](http://codepen.io/andRyanMiller/pen/doNXWa) to give you a feel. I use a directive to set the width and height, which are passed into an isolate scope, then set the `background-image` property when I detect the directive top offset is less than the height of the window. Quick, dirty, but simple implementation of what I think you're going for.

Advantages:

- Aforementioned reprieve from dealing with the ever cantankerous `img` tag.
- Ability to add some neat hover effects (trying hovering over one of the cats in the Codepen).

Drawbacks:

- Detecting image load with a background image isn't quite as easy as using the `img.onload` callback available for image tags. You could likely create directive template that used a `img` to squeeze out this functionality. Up to you.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**: As Chris mentioned in a comment, this technique still doesn't address the aspect ratio issue when the image containers are of varying widths. To solve this I get to whip out one of my favorite CSS tricks, [maintaining aspect ratio with `padding-bottom`](http://nicolasgallagher.com/flexible-css-cover-images/), written about by Nicolas Gallagher.

While unfortunately I don't have time to add the fix into my original pen (headed to work), [I did create this to show an implementation using the same images](http://codepen.io/andRyanMiller/pen/JdEEQV). The `padding-bottom` of an element will proportionally scale as the width of an element increases or decreases, thus maintaining the element's aspect ratio.

Comment: Ah wonderful, this is a good alternative - thanks!  However, this only solves part of the problem since the images here are now a fixed height & width. How can I get them to be flexible to their parent container _and_ stay at the correct aspect ratios? I've forked your demo here.  It's a bit closer, but not 100% there yet: http://codepen.io/chrismbarr/pen/OVWWRJ

Comment: Glad it was of help! Just added an edit to my answer with an addendum covering aspect-ratios and `<divs>`. Wish I had time to fold together my previous Codepen, but the only real step remaining is to calculate the ratio for the property in the `lazyImage` directive.

Comment: excellent, thanks!  I was able to combine these and calculate the image ratios using this technique.  Here's a quisk hard-coded sample of it working: http://codepen.io/chrismbarr/pen/VLpaZP and here's my final working angular demo! http://codepen.io/chrismbarr/pen/mJWPmX

Answer (score -2):

that's kinda simple what you do is

```
    <img src="img.jpg" width"20px" height"20px"/>
```

or any number of pixels and do the same with he other one

```
    <img src="" width"20px" height"20px"/>
```

Comment: No that does not work at all.  This was the first thing I tried.  `<img>` tags without a source do not respect the `width` and `height` properties.  Look at this demo that uses your code: http://codepen.io/chrismbarr/pen/NqddPq

Comment: By the way, using px in width and height attributes is an error. If you want to use px, use CSS.